# How to close multiple pages of Chrome, IE, Excel, Word, Notepad, etc before the start of any BOT in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: batch-file, command, rpa, automationanywhere

I need to close all the previously opened pages of Chrome, IE, Excel, etc. I now need to close of those before the starting of next BOT. How can I achieve this? Is there any built in command in Automation Anywhere through which I can do this? Or can I do with the help of Taskkill command and then create a batch file for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using TaskKill on **Open Program/File** command.

**Command inputs**
Step 1: taskkill.exe
Step 3: /F /IM [task1.exe] /IM [task2.exe] /IM [task1.exe]

**Example:** /F /IM chrome.exe /IM notepad.exe /IM excel.exe

[image]

Comment: Can you please specify whats Step 2 in your answer if any?

Comment: Also in AA window for Step 3 what is the Parameters (optional)...PubMonitor.exe?

Comment: No need to enter a "start in path" in the command, that was the step 2

Comment: That's just an example. You can input  /F /IM chrome.exe /IM notepad.exe /IM excel.exe

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking from creating a separate BAT file for the same and then calling it via this command. So in BAT only I was specifying the taskkill and the other parameters.

Comment: That will work too, but the task will depend on a batch file and the batch file need to upload to the Control Room if you are going to run this bot on another machine or so. 

However, fewer dependencies are better, so if you can do it without a batch file, why not?

Comment: Is there any other alternative for this? Like using "Services" command from AA or any other way?

Comment: Since these are all processes "Services" command will not work, it only will work for services